# Is is possible to locate specific devices on my network based on type of device?

Tags: linux-networking

I have a bunch of Linux-based personal entertainment devices (with displays) that are connected to the network. I often have the need to SSH into them to set certain information. It takes me a while to get the IP address of each one by navigating through it's menus.

The devices are all located on our internal network and have similar IP addresses. They will all be something like 10.107.10.XXX.

I usually use TeraTerm and SSH into each unit using (root login & password) to set whatever parameters I need to. I was hoping I could scan a range of my IP addresses and looking at port 22, I can determine if I have a device there.

What's the best way to determine if I have a device connected and what's its IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nmap -p 22 -Pn 10.107.10.0-50

I had one device connected. See result below using above command.

Nmap scan report for 10.107.10.27
Host is up (0.0010s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh